# Why does rebuilding programs with `cargo build-bpf` take so long in a workspace?

Tags: rust, build-bpf

Compared to the normal `cargo build --release --workspace`, rebuilding a program with `cargo build-bpf` (or sbf) ends up redoing quite a bit of work. If you have already built the workspace using `cargo build`, it caches that result and doesn't try to rebuild if nothing has changed. [image: cargo build --release not recompiling anything on rebuild]

Is there a reason `cargo build-bpf` doesn't have this same behavior? It appears to build each package in the workspace individually. Is there a reason for this? Is there a path forward that builds all the programs together like normal `cargo build`s instead of one at a time?

Answer (score 3):

In normal cases, the build artifacts are cached, like with normal `cargo`.

For example, if you try to build the SPL token program at https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/tree/master/token/program twice, on the second round you'll see:

```
$ cargo build-sbf
    Finished release [optimized] target(s) in 0.24s
```

It could be that your program's transitive dependencies have different features enabled on the same crate, which forces multiple compilations of the same crate, which need to be recompiled on every subsequent build. This is a known "feature" of cargo, however.

Edit: sorry, I missed the "workspace" part of this. This is a bug with `cargo build-sbf`

Comment: Gotcha! Thank you! Is there an open issue on the bug and/or somewhere I can read up on it a bit more?

Comment: Not currently... https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/issues/25765 mentions that it might be tripping up cargo's cache checks, but the resolution to the issue simply consolidates cargo features. It might be worth a new issue